# Why my JS path-finder algorythm isn't work when I change the matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, logic, path-finding

I've to make a code that run a matrix to find the sorthest path to '9' (only walking above the ones, and avoiding the zeros)

In the example below The result correct (5 steps), but if I change the matrix elements positions, the result came wrong..

What can I do? I appreciate any help.

```
var matrix = 
[[1,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,0],
[0,1,0,1],
[0,1,9,1],
[1,1,1,1]]

function runMatrix(matrix){
    newPos = 0;
    var resultr;
    var resultc;


    for( var i = 0, lenR = matrix.length; i < lenR; i++ ) {
        for(var j = 0, lenC = matrix[i].length; j < lenC; j++){
            if( matrix[i][j] == 9 ) {
                resultr = i;
                resultc = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < resultr; i++ ) {
        var k = 0;
        if(matrix[i+1][k] == 1){
            if(matrix[i+1][k+1] == 9 || matrix[i+1][k-1] == 9){
                newPos = newPos + 2;
            }else{
                newPos = newPos + 1;
            }
        }else{
            for(k = 1; k < resultc; i++){
                if(matrix[i][k] == 1 || matrix[i][k] == 9){
                    newPos = newPos + 1
                    if(matrix[i+1][k] == 1){
                        if(matrix[i+1][k+1] == 9 || matrix[i+1][k-1] == 9){
                            newPos = newPos + 2;
                        }else{
                            newPos = newPos + 1;
                        }
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    console.log("Steps: "+newPos)
}
runMatrix(matrix)
```

**update**
this matrix doens't work, for example:

```
[[1,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,1],
[0,0,9,1],
[0,0,0,0]]
```

It returns 4

Comment: Can you provide an example of a matrix that doesn’t work?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. You can step through your code with a debugger and find out what’s wrong.

Comment: Your code actually throws an error when you insert this matrix. Why are you only looping up to `resultr` or `resultc`? You’re also incrementing `i` in `for(k = 1; k < resultc; i++)` while iterating with `k`. After replacing it, it results in “Steps: 1”, not “Steps: 4”.

Comment: I'd tried to do with matrix.lenght, but it isn't work too